# Debug Node.js - The iisnode module is unable to deploy supporting files necessary to initialize the debugger

Tags: node.js, azure, iisnode

I get the following error when I try to debug a node.js application using Azure SDK for Node.js:

The iisnode module is unable to deploy supporting files necessary to initialize the debugger. Please check that the identity of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the node.js application is located.

I have installed the full version of iisnode and added the config settings in web.config. Here is an example of what I type in the browser:

> `http://server:81/server.js/debug`

. The application is using IIS Express to run that is provided in the latest Windows Azure SDK for Node.js - August 2012.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you RDP into your instance and check that IUSR and IIS_IUSRS both have read and write permission on the application folder?

Comment: The problem is on local development not in Azure deployment. Local dev uses IIS Express and run under your current credentials, but to make sure I gave IUSR, IIS_IUSRS and Everyone full access on application directory.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure then I'm afraid.  I don't know IIS express, but I can debug node applications running in IIS 7.5 (the full version on win2k8), but I do see that error when the application directory is not writable by those accounts.  Did you reset iis after changing the permissions just in case?

Comment: Jip, under full IIS everything is working. Just would like to solve the IIS Express issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues here, depending on which version of the Azure SDK for Node you are running:

(1) If you are running a version < 0.6, then this is almost certainly a permissions issue with your webrole directory.  Note that, in IIS, it's the actual web role directory and not the directory in local_package.csx that is actually used in the web role.  Make sure that iiS_IUSRS has write access to this directory and it should work.

(2) If you are running a version >= 0.6, then the problem is that you are using an iisnode version that isn't iis full inside iisexpress.  You can get around this by editing setup_web.cmd to use the path to the iisnode dll in your iisnode directory (rather than the iisnode-dev directory or the SDK directory).